# how to open vs solution file after cloning repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I successfully cloned git repository from remote url to my hard drive.

Now I'm able to open any file but I cannot open visual studio solution file .sln.

When I click on the sln file nothing happens.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple or previous installations of VS in your computer? What happens if you try to open the sln file directly from within VS?

Comment: @Dai now I see that I can open this sln with open with popup menu, altough it's strange that double click cannot open sln now it's working. THanks

Comment: @panjo: that's most probably a problem with you windows file associations, and has nothing to do with git or the file itself

Comment: yep, but all others sln file works open correctly.